# 20 wrong pick at an odds of 1:7 - is it just a bad luck?

Tags: probability

My math is pretty weak, so I decided to ask the experts instead.

Is it acceptable to be wrong 20 times straight at an odds of 1:7, or was the odds wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing $(7/8)^{20}$?

Comment: What is "being acceptable"?

Comment: With $20$ independent repetitions of a *fair trial* with $1/8$ chance to succeed, the probability of failing every single time is $(7/8)^{20} \sim 6.9%$. So this is unlucky, but it certainly isn’t very unlikely either. If you wrote a scientific paper about this, for instance, such odds will not be considered sufficient to prove that the odds were stacked against you.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.

In my simplistic math, 3 being the closest to said odds - 21 divided by 7 equals 3. I was expecting between 1 to 3.

As Mindlack stated, hitting the failing chance of 6.9% for 20 times straight isn't considered to be unlikely, I'll take it at his words. Too bad it wasn't a bet where I could switch to the other side instead.